# Ukrainian with permant German residency, do I need a visa for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, german-residents, ukrainian-citizens

I am a Ukrainian with permanent German residency.
Do I need a visa for the UK?

Answer (score 4):

Yes https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y Permanent residency status elsewhere in the EU does not allow Ukrainian citizens to enter the UK without a visa.